# Prisma delete multiple items by varying field values

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, orm, prisma

I have a model here for Prisma ORM:

```
model User {
    id    Int    @default(@autoincrement())
    name  String
}
```

How would I go about deleting multiple "Users" with only a list of ids?

Here's what I have:

```js
prisma.user.deleteMany({
    where: {
        id: {
            includes: [0, 1, 3] // Array of user IDs to delete
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follow:

```
prisma.user.deleteMany({
  where: {
    OR: [
      {
        id: user1.id,
      },
      {
        id: user2.id,
      },
    ],
  },
})
```